# Joining unrelated entities in hibernate (after 5.1)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to use the new "ON" clause that was added after Hibernate 5.1. I'm trying to run a query across tables/entities that are not associated and I get an exception that suggests my syntax is wrong.

**Code**

```
System.out.println(org.hibernate.Version.getVersionString()); //5.3.7.Final

String query = " SELECT i FROM Information i JOIN Cat c ON i.catId = c.id JOIN Data d ON c.data.id = d.data.id WHERE i.isNew = false AND i.creationTimestamp <= :offset";

Query typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(query);
typedQuery.setMaxResults(fetchSize);
typedQuery.setParameter("offset", currentTimestamp);

return typedQuery.getResultList();
```

**Exception:**

```
antlr.SemanticException: Path expected for join!
```

**Background Info**

My syntax seems to be the same as what is used in the hibernate feature release -> https://in.relation.to/2016/02/10/hibernate-orm-510-final-release/

I was also following the syntax used in this tutorial -> https://thoughts-on-java.org/how-to-join-unrelated-entities/

Answer (score 0):

My answer is biased since I'm developing this technology. But [FluentJPA](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA) will solve your problem since it generates native SQL.

Comment: This is a really really cool idea. If I'm reading your doc correct you want to turn SQL query strings into actual java code for type safety. How far along is the code?

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil: fairly mature. The byte code analyzer is based on the library I'm developing since 2014 (produces AST). AST -> SQL part is new, but covered with tests comprehensively. From JPA integration perspective, many-to-many association support is still missing, also some advanced annotations related to overrides. Risk of adoption is small, since you can always write the query "the usual way".